# What is the Math.Net equivalent of Numpy.dot for 1d and Nd Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am looking for a [Math.NET Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) equivalent for the [Numpy.dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for non symmetrical Matricies.

> np.dot: For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D arrays to inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation). For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(2, 3) * 0.01
b = np.random.randn(3, 1) * 0.01

a
array([[ 0.01543693,  0.0090974 ,  0.00835993],
   [ 0.00475191,  0.00953389, -0.00854795]])

b
array([[ 0.00853528],
   [ 0.00428625],
   [-0.0110117 ]])

np.dot(a, b)
array([[  7.86952720e-05],
   [  1.75551012e-04]])
```

I have tried: `Matrix<float>.op_DotMultiply` and various other methods but none give what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well, to me, dot product and * are different Beasts:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

Matrix<double> a = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] 
{
    { 0.01543693, 0.0090974, 0.00835993 },
    { 0.00475191, 0.00953389, -0.00854795 }
});

Matrix<double> b = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] 
{
    { 0.00853528 },
    { 0.00428625},
    { -0.0110117 }
});

Console.WriteLine("{0:0}", (a * b).ToString());
```

Gives:

```
DenseMatrix 2x1-Double
7.86952E-05
0.000175551
```

So Numpy.dot is the same as Math.Net `M * M` for Non-Symmetrical Matricies? This makes no sense to me!